# Can't understand how to write Junit tests

Tags: java, junit

```
public Card(final int theValue, final int theSuit) {
    this.value = theValue;
    this.suit = theSuit;
}

/**
 * Returns the suit of this card.
 * @returns the suit, which is one of the constants Card.SPADES, 
 * Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER
 */
public int getSuit() {
   return suit;
}
```

I can not understand how to write the tests correctly for `getSuit()`.

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Create a `Card` and assert `getSuit()` returns the value given in the constructor.

Comment: You may not need a unit test specifically and only for a simple getter like this one.

Comment: As an aside, why not use an enum for spades, hearts, diamonds, club and joker? Would save you from documenting the possible return values.

Comment: ok, thank you guys! will try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to make sure that `getSuit()` always returns a valid value, which you have indicated in the method description:

```
@returns the suit, which is one of the constants Card.SPADES, 
Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER
```

Imagine the surprise that you would get if you would get another value than one of those. Code should always only do that what you expect from it. This is called the principle of *least surprise*.

Of course, it is easy to specify an invalid suit in the current constructor in your current code. You should not let your object get into an invalid state, so you should make sure that no other values are accepted by the constructor. Don't forget to also disallow *negative* values. Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the suit integer is out of bounds. Not accepting invalid values is adhering to the the *fail fast* principle.

Using an enum, as specified in the comments, would certainly help with this, as you cannot assign it any value outside the defined range. Don't forget that enum values are objects, and parameters / variables holding them can be `null`, which is also a value that you don't want to accept or return.

Note that, as such, the real method that you are *testing is the constructor*, as no calculations or operations are performed in the getter; you should definitely not throw exceptions in a getter (if it can be avoided).

Comment: When it comes to that, you could also specify an enum for a value, as I'm not sure what kind of value a king has, unless you're generating this for a very specific game. Heck, an ace can have two different values in black jack and the 9 is worth 14 points and considered higher than a 10 in others. I suppose you cannot take anything at face value when playing cards :P